# Handling a lot of data in Java servlet

Tags: java, json, facebook, servlets, facebook-graph-api

what I am trying to do is reading the latest statuses from all my facebook friends 
using graph api ,it takes too long , I am getting all my friends for facebook as json and I read the latest statuses from them , what I am getting is timeout , I know it will take too long to do , but what the efficient way to handle such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

break that into batches and probably do it in separate threads (since most of this will be IO work).

Comment: @salah why not ? you just need to take care of synchronizing the shared resource.

Comment: great , will check this also 
I was thinking if I can send the data as pieces